# NSPredicate compare syntax objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nspredicate

I have the following expression

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value1== %@", variable1];
```

I want to expand the above expression to compare two values e.g."if((value1==variable1)&&(value2==variable2))

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value1== %@ && value2 == %@", variable1, varible2];
```

Check out the [predicate programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215851).